# Remove every nth employee doesn't work

Tags: java

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class vijftienpunt1 {

public static void downsize(LinkedList<String> employeeNames, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < employeeNames.size(); i++) {
        if(i%n==0) {
            employeeNames.remove(i);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<String> employeeNamess = new LinkedList<String>();

    employeeNamess.add("Ab");

    employeeNamess.add("Yo");
    employeeNamess.add("Ik");
    employeeNamess.add("Jij");

    System.out.println(employeeNamess);
    downsize(employeeNamess, 2);
    System.out.println(employeeNamess);
}
}
```

When I run this doesn't work, it removes other nth elements, how can I fix this. I have tried more operations but it still doesn't work

Comment: Try that out eg with playing cards on a desk and you'll quickly notice why it doesn't work. Hint: try reversing the order.

Comment: @fvu i dont still get it

Comment: if tyou remove an element, the indices of the following elements are decreased. That's why it seems to remove "random" elements, and hence my hint.

Comment: @fvu how can i fix that numbers, i am a beginner

Comment: Use Iterator to remove elements

Comment: Iterate in reverse order or use the `Iterator` explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Use Iterator whenever you want to remove elements from list.

try below code:

```
public static void downsize(LinkedList<String> employeeNames, int n) {
    int i=1;
    Iterator<String> iter=employeeNames.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        iter.next();
        if(i%n==0) {
            iter.remove();
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How can i fix this in a forloop,? I have tried it, but my version doesn't work